# asp:Menu Not working on webhost

Tags: asp.net, aspmenu-control

I'm using Visual Studio Web Express 2008 to develop an ASP.Net website. I have a master page that every page inherits from and on that master page I have the asp:menu control. On my local machine the menu control works just fine. The javascript is emitted and the links work as well.

However, when I upload it to my webhost service provider, the javascript is not emitted and my links do not work. I'm getting a feeling that my service provider really doesn't know much about .Net as they suggested that I make sure that I upload the .js files which isn't necessary.

Does anyone have any suggestions that I can give them? They're asking me what requirements are needed. It seems to me that something is not setup on their server properly but according to them, they have .Net 3.5 SP1 installed.

Comment: Did you try other webhosts? Deploy it anywhere else than the development machine? It's quite localized anyways.. Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Everything for the control should be in the framework  (no extra steps necessary); make sure in IIS they set it up to use the 2.0 version of the framework (which is probably the case)...

The cases of errors where I've seen that is when the framework isn't installed.

Answer (score 0):

there is an http debugging tool called [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) that will help you to see what is going wrong with the menu and related site resources. See the requests those are returing 404 and it will help you a lot to head towards the solution faster